# How to display taxonomy in multiselect checkbox front-end with hierarchical terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have some taxonomies and one of it is property type, and on the taxonomy dropdown, taxonomies are showed in hierarchy. but how can I show a hierarchical dropdown list with checkbox?. How can I alter this code? [Here, I wanna display it in front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn2ii.png)

Any help is massively appreciated!.

```
<?php
/** The taxonomy we want to parse */
$taxonomy = "property_type_taxonomy";
/** Get all taxonomy terms */
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array(
        "orderby"    => "count",
        "hide_empty" => false
    )
);
/** Get terms that have children */
$hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy($taxonomy);
?>
<select name="terms" id="terms" multiple>
    <?php
        /** Loop through every term */
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            /** Skip term if it has children */
            if($term->parent) {
                continue;
            }
            echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
            /** If the term has children... */
            if($hierarchy[$term->term_id]) {
                /** ...display them */
                foreach($hierarchy[$term->term_id] as $child) {
                    /** Get the term object by its ID */
                    $child = get_term($child, "property_type_taxonomy");
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '"> - ' . $child->name . '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the "property_type_taxonomy" from your $child.
result should be this :

```
<?php
/** The taxonomy we want to parse */
$taxonomy = "property_type_taxonomy";
/** Get all taxonomy terms */
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array(
        "orderby"    => "count",
        "hide_empty" => false
    )
);
/** Get terms that have children */
$hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy($taxonomy);
?>
<select name="terms" id="terms" multiple>
    <?php
        /** Loop through every term */
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            /** Skip term if it has children */
            if($term->parent) {
                continue;
            }
            echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
            /** If the term has children... */
            if($hierarchy[$term->term_id]) {
                /** ...display them */
                foreach($hierarchy[$term->term_id] as $child) {
                    /** Get the term object by its ID */
                    $child = get_term($child);
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '"> - ' . $child->name . '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```